# Counting nilpotent self-maps of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with image of a given cardinal

Tags: co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{C}_n$ be the monoid of self-maps $\alpha$ of $\{1\dots,n\}$ that are order-preserving ($\forall x,y$, $x\le y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha(x)\le\alpha(y)$ and decreasing ($\forall x$, $\alpha(x)\le x$).

Let N($\mathcal{C_n})$ be the set of nilpotent elements of $\mathcal{C}_n$, i.e., those $\alpha\in\mathcal{C}_n$ such that some power of $\alpha$ equals the absorbing element (the constant function $1$). As mentioned in a comment, this means that $\alpha(x)<x$ for every $x>1$.

> Given $r$, what is the cardinality of the subset
> $$X_{n,r}=\{\alpha\in N(\mathcal{C_n}): \lvert \mathrm{im}(\alpha)\rvert=r\}?$$

Comment: What is $\mathcal{C}_n$?

Comment: $\mathcal{C}_n$ is all order-preserving and decreasing transformations. For exampe $N(\mathcal{C}_2)=
\left\{\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1  & 2 \\ 1  & 1 \end{array}\right) \right\}$ and $\mathcal{C}_2=
\left\{\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1  & 2 \\ 1  & 1 \end{array}\right),
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1  & 2 \\ 1  & 2 \end{array}\right) \right\}$

Comment: In case someone is as slow as me, the order being discussed is the usual ordering of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$, the all-$1$ map is the zero element of this semigroup, and the matrices listed do **not** represent linear transformations.

Comment: See Narayana numbers - on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number) or [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001263)

Comment: @VilleSalo You seem to be right; the $n\times2$-matrices represent self-maps of $\{1,...,n\}$

Comment: What does "order preserving and decreasing" mean? I thought that order-preserving maps are the same as "increasing".

Comment: Yes I think the $2 \times n$ matrices list images of elements. I suppose it's a standard enough notation, but $n = 3$ would've been less confusing. Anyway, I have no idea about the answer.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Order preserving means $f(k)\leqslant f(k+1)$; decreasing (more accurately, non-increasing) means $f(k)\leqslant k$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Order-preserving means if $x\leq y$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$; decreasing means $f(x)\leq x$ for all $x,y\in X_n=\{1,2,\dots, n\}$. Notice that I take into account of nilpotent elements and so $f(x)< x$.

Comment: @1Spectre1 Note an image-preserving bijection $N(\mathcal C_n)\to\mathcal C_{n-1}$ sending $f$ to $\hat f$ with $\hat f(x)=f(x+1)$.

Comment: I incorporated the relevant definitions in the question.

Comment: It is strange definition for me. Say, "decreasing function" usually means "$x<y \Rightarrow f(x)\geqslant f(y)$"

Comment: The number of elements of $C_n$ is the n-th catalan number.  This monoid $C_n$ is called the catalan monoid. A lot of people have studied this monoid.  The size of the image set is called the rank. So you want the number of nilpotent elements of rank r in the catalan monoid.   Mostly likely this is known in the literature and Andy Solomon wrote a lot about various generalizations but I don't have the literature in front of me and I'm not the best at counting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is ${n-2\choose r-1}{n-1\choose r-1}-{n-2\choose r-2}{n-1\choose r}=\frac1{n-r}{n-2\choose r-1}{n-1\choose r}$.

Let $\{1=a_0<a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_{r-1}\}$ be the image of $\alpha\in X_{n,r}$ and denote $p_i:=\max \alpha^{-1}(a_{i-1})$ for $i=1,\ldots,r-1$. Then $p_1<p_2<\ldots p_{r-1}<n$ and $p_i\geqslant a_i$ for all $i$. Now define two lattice paths (with vertical steps $+(0,1)$ and horizontal steps $+(1,0)$). The first path goes from $A=(1,0)$ to $C=(n-r,r-1)$ and has vertices at points $(a_i-i,i-1)$ and $(a_i-i,i)$ for $i=1,\ldots, r-1$. The second goes from $B=(1,-1)$ to $D=(n+1-r,r-2)$ and has the vertices $(p_i-i+1,i-2)$ and $(p_i-i+1,i-1)$.
They should be disjoint, and any disjoint pair of paths from $A$ to $C$ and from $B$ to $D$ corresponds to some nilpotent map $\alpha\in X_{n,r}$.

Note that there is no pair of disjoint paths from $A$ to $D$ and from $B$ to $C$. So we get the above formula using [Lindstrőm–Gessel–Viennot lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%E2%80%93Gessel%E2%80%93Viennot_lemma)
: the $2\times 2$ matrix which counts the lattice paths from $\{A,B\}$ to $\{C,D\}$ is just $$\pmatrix{{n-2\choose r-1}&{n-2\choose r-2}\\
{n-1\choose r}& {n-1\choose r-1}
&}.$$

Comment: Algebraically, it looks like you could rewrite your formula by replacing $n-1$ by $n-2$, which seems to simplify further to $\frac{n-1}{k(n-k)}{\binom{n-2}{k-1}}^2$. Gerhard "Giving Fewer Subexpressions To Evaluate" Paseman, 2019.12.20.

Comment: @1Spectre1 I added some clarifications, is it more clear now? Sincerely, I do not understand which bijection do you ask about. The sequences of $a'$s and $p's$ and pairs of lattice paths?

Comment: @FedorPetrov thank you. Is it possible  to count  it just using elementary method ?

Comment: What is not elementary here? two by two determinant?

Comment: I think, the argument is pretty combinatorial. You shoul count the pairs of disjoint AC, BD paths. For this you subtract from all pairs of paths the pairs which are not disjoint. The not-disjoint pairs are in bijection with pairs of AD, BC paths. Bijection is the following: take the first point P on the AC path which belongs also to BD path and switch the continuations beyond $P$ of both paths .

Comment: @FedorPetrov How have you determined $C$, $D$ and vertices points.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand youк question. $C$ and $D$ are defined in the answer, aren't they?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I dont take any lesson about lattice paths. I am not good. Therefore I have tried to understand your answer. You construct first path from $A$ to $C=(n-r,r-1)$ and has vertices at points $(a_i-i,i-1)$ and $(a_i-i,i)$. Why did you take  $C=(n-r,r-1)$? How have you constucted vertices of paths? Similar questions for second paths?I  couldn't understand well how  this paths coincidince with $X_{n,r}$. 
If you explain on an example, I would be very thankful. I take $X_{4,2}$.

Comment: It is not a big science, you should not take special lessons. Choose your favourite $\alpha\in X_{4,2}$ and draw these paths as they are defined.

Comment: Yes I can see for $X_{4.2}$. I dont understand why did you take $C=(n-r,r-1)$ and $D=(n+1-r,r-2)$? .

Comment: I take $C=(n-r,r-1)$, because I have a vertex $(a_{r-1}-(r-1),r-1)$, the abscissa $a_{r-1}-(r-1)$ of this point is at most $n-1-(r-1)=n-r$. So I always may add a horizontal segment from this vertex to $(n-r,r-1)$. And any path from $(1,0)$ to $(n-r,r-1)$ corresponds to such a sequence $1=a_0<a_1<\ldots<a_{r-1}\leqslant n-1$. Analogously with $BD$-path and their non-intersection.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, In answer yo say vertical steps +(1,0) and horizontal steps +(0,1). I think vertical steps +(0,1) and horizontal steps +(1,0).

Comment: @1Spectre1 correct, fixed

Answer (score 7):

მამუკა ჯიბლაძე is right, these are the [Narayana numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number).

You are studying functions $f$ obeying $f(2) \leq \cdots \leq f(n)$ and $1 \leq f(j) \leq j-1$ for $2 \leq j \leq n$. Draw the path from $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$ made up of horizontal line segments from $(j,f(j+1))$ to $(j+1,f(j+1))$ for $1 \leq j \leq n-1$ and vertical line segments from $(j,f(j))$ to $(j,f(j+1))$ for $2 \leq j \leq n$, where we formally put $f(n+1)=n$. This is a bijection between your functions and paths from $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$ which travel up and right while staying below the line $y=x+1$. The number of such paths is the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), and you can see these paths (rotated and reflected) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number#Combinatorial_interpretations) for $n=5$.

You want to count $f$ according to the size of this image, which is the number of horizontal segments in the path. This is also the number of bottom left corners of the path. As Wikipedia says, Narayana numbers count paths by the number of such corners (which they call peaks, because their paths are rotated and reflected).

Comment: Narayana numbers :$N(n,k)=\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}$. For  examlpe $\lvert X_ {5,3}\rvert =6\neq N(5,3)=20$

Comment: I think answer is  $\frac{1}{n-r}\binom{n-2}{r-1}\binom{n-1}{r}$

Comment: Okay, let's trace through the indexing. Nilpotent functions $[n] \to [n]$ are paths $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$, which are counted by Narayana numbers $N(n-1,\ast)$. The size of the image is the number of peaks, so $|X_{n,r}|$ should be $N(n-1,r)$. As you say, $N(n-1,r) = \tfrac{(n-1)! (n-1)!}{(n-1) r! (r-1)! (n-r-1)! (n-r)!} = \tfrac{(n-1)! (n-2)!}{(n-r) r! (r-1)! (n-r-1)! (n-r-1)!} = \tfrac{1}{n-r} \binom{n-2}{r-1} \binom{n-1}{r}$.

Comment: @ DES-SupportsMonicaAndTransfolk  Thank you for answer. I dont use this method before. I couldnt  establish function for bijectivity.  I  dont express as a set paths $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$.

Comment: For example, $X_{4,2}\rightarrow ?$ is a bijecton.